# React navgiation AppRegistry is not registered

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have setup a brand new project using `react-native init <proj>` and it builds fine. I have added `react-navigation` to the project following the docs. However, I cannot get passed this error:

`Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

Even using the single file stack example from their documentation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

It does not work. I am at a loss to what the issue could be here as I am using a base install with their working example and nothing else added. I have tried everything from restarting the bundler to clearing all caches I can think of.

Comment: Did you run `react-native link react-navigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're registering the component:

```js
const App = createAppContainer(navigator):

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)
```